# Model for an AppWidgetProvider

Tags: android, widget

I have a widget that shows some data fetched from the Internet. I may have multiple widgets visible on the screen, each displaying some data, partly the same as the other widgets.

From time to time I re-fetch the data from the Internet and update the widget views.

I've modeled this in an MVC style: I have a model which I can invoke a "re-fetch-data" on, and which the views listen on.

My questions:

**A)** Is it wise to let my model be a singleton?

**B)** Can I rely on that all widgets are served by the same AppWidgetProvider? Or may some of my widgets get served by a different AppWidgetProvider instance? Or, more generally: Is there any guarantee that there will be only one instance of my AppWidgetProvider?

If there is only one instance of my AppWidgetProvider, then I could use an instance variable here for the model, and pass either my AppWidgetProvider or the model around where needed. Perhaps a better option?

**C)** In the AppWidgetProviders `onUpdate` method, can I be sure that the same "context" object is passed as argument each invocation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it wise to let my model be a
>   singleton?

Considering you can't have static data in an `AppWidgetProvider`, I would say a singleton is extremely unsafe. You need to use a persistent store, such as a file or database.

> Can I rely on that all widgets are
>   served by the same AppWidgetProvider?

It will be the same class. It most definitely [will not be the same instance](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#ReceiverLifecycle), unless you are doing some really evil stuff, like trying to have an everlasting service.

> Or may some of my widgets get served
>   by a different AppWidgetProvider
>   instance?

Yes.

> Or, more generally: Is there any guarantee that there will be only one instance of my AppWidgetProvider?

There is a guarantee there will **NOT** be only one instance of your `AppWidgetProvider`. ["If this BroadcastReceiver was launched through a  tag, then the object is no longer alive after returning from this function."](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive(android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent))

> In the AppWidgetProviders onUpdate
>   method, can I be sure that the same
>   "context" object is passed as argument
>   each invocation?

I do not think that is a safe assumption.

Comment: Wow. Great answer. I have some serious refactoring ahead!